# Retrieving complicated nested values in Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, input, jquery-selectors, nested

I have a form that can dynamically generate li elements containing an image and six inputs. Each generated line takes the form:

```
<li>
    <div id="ShowcaseEntry" class="IndexEntry">
        <div class="IndexImage">
            <img src="/static/graphics/no-image.png" alt="/static/graphics/no-image.png">
        </div>
        <div class="IndexCaption">
            <label>Caption</label><br />
            En <input type="text" class="ShowcaseCaption_en" value="">
            Es <input type="text" class="ShowcaseCaption_es" value="">
            <br />
            <label>Link</label><br />
            En <input type="text" class="ShowcaseLink_en" value="">
            Es <input type="text" class="ShowcaseLink_es" value="">
            <br/>
            <a href="" class="removeimg">Remove</a></li>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The unordered list has the ID ShowcaseImages.

Previously the image was not inside a division of its own and when the form was submitted there was a JQuery function that collected up all the image source names:

```
var galleryimagesinput = [];
$("#ShowcaseImages li img").each(function() { galleryimagesinput.push($(this).attr('src')) });
```

I could then send the array through a single input value in the form to be disassembled at the other end.

However, now the image is inside a div the src isn't collected. How do I collect the src and how would I collect the values for each caption and link text in each li putting them in arrays of their own (one for images, one for captions, one for link texts)

I know this is probably just a question of chaining selectors but I'm completely lost with it. The actual input values sent from the text boxes directly to the form aren't important as I intend Jquery to gather them up to be placed into other hidden inputs.

Comment: what does the new html look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#ShowcaseImages li").each(function() { 
    galleryimagesinput.push($(this).find('img').attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: if `li img` selector doesn't work...why would this? Same thing basically

Comment: @charlietfl - Because in the OP's original selector he's iterating over all the images within the list items. This selector iterates over the list items instead, and then grabs the image in each one.

Comment: Both Pat's and this one work but I've managed to tweak this one for picking up the captions and the link texts too. Modded both up, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should run the function for each image within the #ShowcaseImages ul

```
var galleryimagesinput = [];
$("#ShowcaseImages img").each(function() { 
  galleryimagesinput.push($(this).attr('src')) 
});
```

I've just dropped the 'li' from your original function.